# I am getting this "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'verify')" in reactjs when i am trying to send otp using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

OtpVerification.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { auth, } from '../firebase';
import { signInWithPhoneNumber } from 'firebase/auth';

const OtpVerification = ({ phoneNumber }) => {
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState(null);

  const onSendOtp = () => {
    // Ensure that the phone number is valid before sending OTP
    if (!phoneNumber) {
      console.error('Invalid phone number');
      return;
    }
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    // Send OTP to the provided phone number
    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, `+${phoneNumber}`, appVerifier)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        // Save the verification ID to use later for OTP confirmation
        // setVerificationId(confirmationResult.verificationId);
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        console.log('OTP sent successfully');
        // Additional logic if needed
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error sending OTP:', error);
        // Handle error appropriately
      });
  };

  const onVerify = () => {
    if (!verificationId || !otp) {
      console.error('Invalid verification ID or OTP');
      return;
    }

    // Confirm the OTP using the verification ID
    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, verificationId, otp)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('Phone number verified successfully:', result);
        // Additional logic if needed
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error verifying OTP:', error);
        // Handle error appropriately
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className='otpVerification'>
      <input
        type='number'
        value={otp}
        onChange={(e) => setOtp(e.target.value)}
        maxLength={6}
      />
      <button onClick={onSendOtp}>Send OTP</button>
      <button onClick={onVerify}>Verify</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OtpVerification;
```

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getDatabase} from 'firebase/database';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};



const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getDatabase(app);

export {auth,db};
```

I am trying to send otp on enterd number which is coming form another componet which i am taking as a promt in reactjs. I am  using firebase in react js for otp verication, but i am getting error of TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'verify') what is causing this error? and how can i solve this error? and is there any other easy way of doing  otp verification in reactjs?

Comment: Have you done the reCAPTCHA setup for your project ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth?hl=en&authuser=0#before-you-begin

Answer (score 0):

I have:

1. used `PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, otp)` to get the credentials to be used in `signInWithCredential()` and it's working now. (I think this was the issue with your code)
2. updated the code to handle captcha effectively.

I have used the `async/await` version of the firebase methods (just for my preference feel free to change them).

**OtpVerification.js**

```
import {
  PhoneAuthProvider,
  RecaptchaVerifier,
  signInWithCredential,
  signInWithPhoneNumber,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "./firebase";

const OtpVerification = ({ phoneNumber}) => {
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState("");
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState("");

  const setUpRecaptcha = () => {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
      auth,
      "recaptcha-container",
      {
        size: "invisible",
      }
    );
  };

  const onSendOtp = async () => {
    // Ensure that the phone number is valid before sending OTP
    if (!phoneNumber) {
      console.error("Invalid phone number");
      return;
    }

    if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
      setUpRecaptcha();
    }

    try {
      const result = await signInWithPhoneNumber(
        auth,
        `+${phoneNumber}`,
        window.recaptchaVerifier
      );
      setVerificationId(result.verificationId);
      console.log("OTP sent successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending OTP:", error);
    }
  };

  const onVerify = async () => {
    if (!verificationId || !otp) {
      console.error("Invalid verification ID or OTP");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, otp);
      await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
      console.log("Successfully signed in with OTP");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error signing in with OTP:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setUpRecaptcha();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="otpVerification">
      <input
        type="number"
        value={otp}
        onChange={(e) => setOtp(e.target.value)}
        maxLength={6}
        placeholder="OTP"
      />
      <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
      <button onClick={onSendOtp}>Send OTP</button>
      <button onClick={onVerify}>Verify</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OtpVerification;
```

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import OtpVerification from "./OtpVerification";

export default function App() {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>OTP Verification</h2>
      <div>
        <label>Phone Number:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={phoneNumber}
          onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="918144356767"
        />
      </div>
      <OtpVerification phoneNumber={phoneNumber} />
    </div>
  );
}
```